# Navigation app failed ios 9

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework

I have an application made for iOS ionic until recently and iOS versions prior to 9 runs all excellent. But smartphones with iOS 9 up fails navigation, for example, and something that comes in ionic is the button again when I'm in a view and pressed that button, pretends to return but remains in the same view and we must make 1 or 2 more times attempt to finally prove. I thought it might have been updating ionic or operating system, testie in previous versions and also in other iphones (now I'm trying to iphone 6) and also iPads with iOS versions prior to 9 and everything works great.

The method used to return :

```
$ionicHistory.goBack();
```

Comment: Have you added the angular ios9 fix? http://blog.ionic.io/preparing-for-ios-9/

Comment: Yes, use the following code: bower install angular-ios9-uiwebview-patch But it did not work or I did not apply well, installed the patch but still fails navigation @user1886721

Comment: Have you confirmed that the JS is loaded inside a <script> tag? Bower is not configured by default to load additional JS.

Comment: If, in fact this in my index.html : <script scr="js/angular-ios9-uiwebview.patch.js"></script>

Comment: @user1886721 perhaps we will have to do more than I have done?

Comment: please, Put your answer to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo.

```
<script scr="js/angular-ios9-uiwebview.patch.js"></script>
```

should be:

```
<script src="js/angular-ios9-uiwebview.patch.js"></script>
```

Also, please check that the file is present in the js/ directory